# In Mothership Zeta: How to destroy the generators in the Cryo Lab in Among the Stars?

Tags: fallout-3

I am stuck in the Cryo Lab in. The quest marker points there, yet there is nothing to interact with. All I see is a door I am unable to pick as it requires a key. How to continue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quest is [seriously bugged](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Mothership_Zeta_bugs). I was lucky that I had an older save. There is an optional quest to request help from the revived people. Consider it a mandatory one instead for solving this quest without much trouble. Make sure to recruit [Elliot Tercorien](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Elliott_Tercorien), as he interacts with the environment and triggers your progress.